# Append a style on click, then append another style on 2nd click

Tags: jquery

Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/adige72/BbSd7/

When i click to, suppose "show div 1", it removes dotted border-bottom of it but once it clicked again the border does not return whereas what i want it does.

Comment: Could you please post your relevent code here on SO?

Comment: There is a bunch of errors in your JavaScript and in your markup. Could you first tell us what have you been trying to get with your code?

Comment: As you can see the dotted border of each li item disappears after clicking on it which is what i want it to be. But the thing is it doesnt appear again after closing the toggled content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use toggleClass that should do the trick. You're doing an each() which may not be needed. Just hook onto the element that needs to be clicked. Don't need to loop through each parent li etc.

See the first example here: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: Do you do everything just because you can? Why not explain why and be constructive. One would expect more from senior SO'ers

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use classes to manage it as it is much cleaner:

```
$('#element').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('class1')) {
    $(this).addClass('class2');
  }
}
```

With styles it is similar.  An example:

```
$('#element').click(function() {
  if ($(this).css('background-color')=='red') {
    $(this).css('color', 'white');
  }
}
```

Comment: That's effectively toggleClass?

Comment: @MoinZaman you are right it is effectively toggle class although I find the if statement much easier to read.  I did add another using css properties since that was the original question.

Comment: Thanks but i couldn't implement your code to my situation. Is there any way else?

Comment: @Adige72 since you marked the other answer which was identical to mine as the answer it seems that it did work for you which is what is important.